# Dynamic key name (field name ) in joi validation

Tags: joi

I need to validate dynamic key name in joi validation.

Following code is working but i need to change key name dynamic like `'phone'+this.props.date` in following example

```
this.validatorTypes = {
            'phone': Joi.string().min(10).max(10).required().label('Phone').options({
                language: {
                    any: {
                        empty: 'is required'
                    },
                    string: {

                        min: 'length must be {{limit}} characters long'
                    }
                }
            }),
            'name': Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required().label('Name').options({
                language: {
                    any: {
                        empty: 'is required'
                    },
                    string: {

                        min: 'length must be {{limit}} characters long'
                    }
                }
            })

        },
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of some data you'd expect to pass the validation you're after?

Comment: 'phone'+this.props.date: Joi.string()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
['phone'+this.props.date]
```

worked for me

```
['phone'+this.props.date]: Joi.string().min(10).max(10).required().label('Phone').options({
            language: {
                any: {
                    empty: 'is required'
                },
                string: {

                    min: 'length must be {{limit}} characters long'
                }
            }
        }),
        ['name'+this.props.date]: Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required().label('Name').options({
            language: {
                any: {
                    empty: 'is required'
                },
                string: {

                    min: 'length must be {{limit}} characters long'
                }
            }
        })
```